# Using submitdata in Jeditable and in save.php

Tags: javascript, php, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable to edit columns. But during the edit for one particular column I need to send some additional information with the post. To do this I included the submitdata: as seen below.

```
var foo = 12;  var foo2 = 'ABBOT';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').editable('save.php', {
        indicator : "Saving...",
        tooltip   : '',
        style     : "inherit",
        submitdata: function(value, settings) {
            return {
                foo: netID, 
                foo2: cs1
            };
        }
    });
```

The data for foo and foo2 is created in a `var foo = 12` and `var foo2 = 'ABBOT'` (netID and cs1) step above the editable function.
My question is two fold: One is this the correct syntax to pass those values?
Two, in save.php how do I receive those values?

Currently in save.php I have;

```
$rawdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

But I don't understand how to pick up the values of foo and foo2.

If you can and are willing please help me understand how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the edits Jamie, is this a service you provide or just an opportunity for me to learn a better way? Sure could use a solution to my question either way... just saying.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to jquery but have been trying out jeditable. I believe the variables are passed thru the $_REQUEST array so in your php file:

```
$val1 = $_REQUEST['foo'] ;
$val2 = $_REQUEST['foo2'] ;
echo $val1;
echo $val2;
// prints out 12 & ABBOTT
```

I too am stuck on how you pass a variable thru submitdata option. With a static value it is:

```
submitdata : {foo: "12",
              foo2: "ABBOTT"
             }
```